# OCtoberCMS Blog plugin Rainlab

Tags: php, css, laravel, content-management-system, octobercms

When i create a new Post and write in the excerpt, the post image on the news page just dissappears . It only works if i have no excerpt. Also .. How can i create new posts with existing classes already written in my css?

Without the excerpt ir works just fine. Showing image and text that i add on the post.

**My code**

```
<section id="content">

        <div class="content-wrap">

            <div class="container clearfix">



          <div  class="row"> {% component 'blogPosts' %}


          </div>



            </div>

        </div>

    </section><!-- #content end -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When not defining an `excerpt`, a `summary` attribute is appended to the model. See https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/blob/master/models/Post.php#L344 . If your content starts with an image, it might be that the summary function kicks in and generates the image.

As for the CSS part

I think you're looking to override the partial set by `{% componenent 'blogPosts' %}`. As per the docs (https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#overriding-partials)

> All component partials can be overridden using the theme partials. If
>   a component called channel uses the `title.htm` partial. We can override
>   the partial by creating a file in our theme called 
>   `partials/channel/title.htm`.

Alternatively you can `cmd / ctrl + doubleclick` to expand the default component markup inside the CMS editor.

In this way you can edit your markup to match your theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override markup there is really easy way. for image @CptMeatball added proper answer you can check that out.

> This way you have full control on mark-up and you can edit it.

**1. Click on expand component it will reveal `mark-up` of component**

[image]

**2. Now you can add your own markup and edit it.**

[image]

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: I didn't know about that . I was able to get where i wanted within 30 minutes of coding. Thanks. U a life saver ^^

Comment: is answer helpful :) if yes i will leave it here, if not then i will remove it as it may miss-guid others :)